# Consolidate [toilet-training] and [potty-training] and [potty]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Consider the following tags:

[potty-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty-training): 59 questions

[toilet-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training): 13 questions

[potty](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty): 6 questions, 5 of which are potty training, plus a recent question about constipation

[toilet](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet): 6 questions; 1 about constipation-ish, 3 about potty training related things, 2 about toilets in public places

I suggest making [potty](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty) and [toilet-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training) synonyms for [potty-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty-training), and burninating [toilet](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet), replacing it with [toilet-manners](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-manners) or [public-toilet](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-toilet) or something like that (it seems like the 2 public places questions are in part about manners, and there were a few others which would take that as well).

I'm aware that `toilet` has a slightly complictated meaning outside of the US (inside the US it is pretty much a synonym for potty), so I'm not sure this is completely realistic.  However, I think given half the questions are pretty much just potty training questions adding a second related word tag, it makes sense to change it to a different word.

I also think [potty](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty) makes more sense as a potty training synonym, in part because [potty-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty-training) is often entered as "potty training" and having it be a synonym would simplify that.  `toilet` is sufficiently different outside of the US it probably shouldn't be a synonym in my mind, though I would not object if it was.

I've proposed the two synonyms on [potty-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty-training), and would love to get some votes on that as well as feedback; I'd also like feedback on the [toilet](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet) suggestions, as that seems more complex.

Comment: All those of you voting up: please vote on the synonyms!  Go to [tag:potty-training] and click on Synonyms, then vote up the one(s) you agree with.  That's how they get approved (or Karl/Beofett can directly approve them I think, but the community process is often preferred!)  This requires some rep, but not an exorbitant amount, IIRC.

Comment: I agree with this and have upvoted the synonyms. Don't know how to remove toilet, replacing it as you suggest, but I agree there, too.

Comment: Removing (blocking) a word isn't something we can do directly - I'm not sure if it's something moderators can do (Karl/Beofett?) or if it's something you need SE staff to implement.

Comment: I found [this comment from chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15854259#15854259) about tags that I believe will address [tag:toilet], so going to remove that tag or replace appropriately.

Comment: BTW: Reading the definitions of [tag:toilet-training] and [tag:potty-training] is confusing to an American. When is a potty not a toilet?  Could use clarification from someone who knows the answer.

Comment: I think "potty" is the kids potty that some people use (e.g., the little plastic whatnot that usually has a noise-making handle).  I don't think it needs a separate tag, personally.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that [potty-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty-training) and [toilet-training](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet-training) should by synonyms, but I'm not sure if it's worth keeping [potty](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty) nor [toilet](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toilet).

As you've shown, potty and toilet combine still comprise less total tags than toilet-training. Of those questions, only 2/3 are about potty-training.

I would nix toilet for the reasons you gave. It's either not descriptive or lends to double-tagging.

Potty, as a tag, isn't very intuitive, and generally needs to be tagged with something else for context. If I hadn't already seen the questions, I would assume [potty](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty) would be about anything related to going potty (such as training, behavior, health, stools, types of training potties).

However, every question with the tag is already tagged as potty-/toilet-training, making potty useless and not used often enough to be a synonym. (I say *every* question, because the 1 that's about constipation is actually a duplicate of a different question that's only tagged [toddler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toddler) & [health](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health), and absent any potty-related tag).